How to do one auth call for multiple components
I have a React app something like this:
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ExternalContent id="1"/>
      <ExternalContent id="2"/>
      <ExternalContent id="3"/>
      <ExternalContent id="4"/>
      <ExternalContent id="5"/>
    </div>
  );
}

function ExternalContent() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTemporaryAuthToken() {
        const response = await fetch(EXTERNAL_SERVICE_AUTH_URL);
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        setToken(responseJson.token);
    }

    getTemporaryAuthToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={`EXTERNAL_SERVICE_URL\${props.id}?token=${token}`}/>
    </div>
  );
}

Obviously, what happens here is that getTemporaryAuthToken gets called 5 times - once for every instance of the ExternalContent component. However, I want to keep the getTemporaryAuthToken logic within ExternalContent - if I can - as it makes sense to keep them together. I also don't want to move getTemporaryAuthToken up to App because it is not guaranteed that I have to call it (there may not be any instances of ExternalContent to show so getting a token would be unnecessary).
What would be the recommended way to "if there are any ExternalContent components to show, run getTemporaryAuthToken once, then re-use the token for all of them)"?
Sorry if I'm missing something obvious

In those cases, there are no other options, so you should use context or external store libraries (like Redux, MobX, etc.). Since a component is a JavaScript function, one instance cannot have information about others. You can also lift the state up.


import { useState, useEffect, createContext, useContext, useMemo } from "react";

export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ExternalProvider>
        {/* <ExternalProvider2> */}
        <ExternalContent />
        <ExternalContent />
        <ExternalContent />
        <ExternalContent />
        <ExternalContent />
        {/* </ExternalProvider2> */}
      </ExternalProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

function ExternalContent() {
  const { token, setToken } = useExternalContext();

  //you can leave logic here, but potentially it can make problems for the feature
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTemporaryAuthToken() {
      const response = await fetch("/...");
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      setToken(responseJson.token);
    }

    if (!token) {
      getTemporaryAuthToken();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe src={`EXTERNAL_SERVICE_URL\${props.id}?token=${token}`} />
    </div>
  );
}

const ExternalContext = createContext();
const ExternalContext2 = createContext();

const ExternalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ token, setToken }), [token]);

  return (
    <ExternalContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ExternalContext.Provider>
  );
};


const ExternalProvider2 = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);

  //In my opinion it's better way to leave logic here and use trigger
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTemporaryAuthToken() {
      const response = await fetch("/...");
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      setToken(responseJson.token);
    }

    if (trigger) {
      getTemporaryAuthToken();
    }
  }, [trigger]);

  const triggerTokenInitialization = async () => setTrigger(true);

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ token, triggerTokenInitialization }), [token]);

  return (
    <ExternalContext2.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ExternalContext2.Provider>
  );
};

const useExternalContext = () => useContext(ExternalContext);
const useExternalContext2 = () => useContext(ExternalContext2);



